# how to apply css for the data fetched from the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fetching the datas from the database...And the datas are displayed as dropdownmenu but the css is not applied

---

```
  <ul id="nav">
  <?php
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE PARENT_ID=0");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
        echo "<li class='top'><a href='#' class='top_link'>".$row['MENU_NAME']."</a></li>";
    $res1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE PARENT_ID=1 AND CHILD_ID=".$row['ID']."");

        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($res1))
          {

             echo "<ul  class='sub'><li class='top'><a href='#' >".$row1['MENU_NAME']."</li></ul>";
             $res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE PARENT_ID=2 AND CHILD_ID=".$row1['ID']."");
             echo "<ul>";
             while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2))
                {
                        echo "<ul><li class='fly'><a href='#'>".$row2['MENU_NAME']."</li></ul>";
                }
             echo "</ul>";
          }
          echo "</ul>";
  }





  ?>
  </ul>
  <h1> </h1>


  <hr/>
```

this is my view page 
 my datas must be arranged in such a order that datas in the class='top' must be arrrived as as the main menu
the datas in the class="sub" must be arrivd as submenu 
the datas in the class="fly" must be arrived as sub menu to the submenu
The format is
->main menu
  -> submenu1->submenu11
             ->submenu12

-> submenu2
  -> submenu3
when i give hard coded datas i am receiving in order that when i hover main menu 
submenu will be displayed ..
the hard coded code is

Products

Cameras

- Nikon

when i hover submenu.. A submenu of the sub menu is be displayed
I got these results 
How can apply the css to the datas fetchded from th database
my whole view page is




 stu nicholls dot com | menu - Professional dropdown #2

Products

Cameras

- Nikon

---

```
  <ul id="nav">
  <?php
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE PARENT_ID=0");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
        echo "<li class='top'><a href='#' class='top_link'>".$row['MENU_NAME']."</a></li>";
    $res1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE PARENT_ID=1 AND CHILD_ID=".$row['ID']."");

        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($res1))
          {

             echo "<ul  class='sub'><li class='top'><a href='#' >".$row1['MENU_NAME']."</li></ul>";
             $res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE PARENT_ID=2 AND CHILD_ID=".$row1['ID']."");
             echo "<ul>";
             while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2))
                {
                        echo "<ul><li class='fly'><a href='#'>".$row2['MENU_NAME']."</li></ul>";
                }
             echo "</ul>";
          }
          echo "</ul>";
  }





  ?>
  </ul>
  <h1> </h1>


  <hr/>
```

Can anyone give me suggestion

Comment: Your question only includes HTML and PHP code. How about showing us the CSS code that is giving you issues?

Comment: looks like you have not included the css file or are missing that in your file.

Comment: CSS works on HTML, not PHP or SQL. You should inspect the HTML in your browser's View Source menu.

Comment: Why did you tag it with CodeIgniter when you obviously are not using it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly a solution for your problem but why are you using a framework such as CI, which works around the MVC-principle and in the meantime have PHP and SQL statements in your view?

I suggest you read up on these CI topics:

- Template parser:
  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/parser.html
- Database (active record):
  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html
- Views: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html

What's the CSS you're currently using?